# Add multiple attachments from While statement to email argument

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, arguments, email-attachments

I'm working with legacy code and trying to update their email code from a bunch of multiple email code to a single call. I've been successful until I ran into a `While Wend` statement for attachments.

I'm using the following `Public Sub` to call these emailers.

```
Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal recipient As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal bodyText As String, SendDisplay As Boolean, Optional ByVal carboncopy As String, Optional attachment0 As String, Optional attachment1 As String, Optional attachement2 As String, Optional attachement3 As String, Optional attachement4 As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Shell "outlook.exe", vbNormalFocus
    Else
        AppActivate objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Caption
    End If
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With OutApp
        .Session.Logon
        Set OutMail = .CreateItem(olMailItem)
    End With
    With OutMail
        .To = recipient
        If carboncopy <> "" Then
            .CC = carboncopy
        End If
        .subject = subject
        .Body = bodyText
        If attachment0 <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add attachment0
        End If
        If attachment1 <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add attachment1
        End If
        If attachment2 <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add attachment2
        End If
        If attachment3 <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add attachment3
        End If
        If attachment4 <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add attachment4
        End If
        If SendDisplay Then
            .Display True
        Else
            .Send
        End If
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The snippet I am having an issue with is code that attaches all files in a folder with a `While Wend` loop.

```
    With OutMail
        While Len(strFileName) > 0
              .Attachments.Add (strDir & strFileName)
              strFileName = Dir
        Wend
        .subject = (MySub)
        .Body = strbody
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain '1
        .Display True
    End With
```

I'm trying to convert the above `With` to

```
SendEmail "", (MySub), strbody, True, , ???
```

My question is what is the best way to get these attachments from this `While Wend` loop?

The code is located in a userform and all the files are created when the form loads and exports selected worksheets from a ComboBox and a button to Export is pressed as a PDF to a folder.

Is there a way to use `While` to add the files to the argument for attaching in the SendEmail sub? Is there a way to add these files to the argument from the folder?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT FOR CLEARER EXPLANATION**

When the Userform is initialized it will load all visible worksheets in to ComboBox1. An item is selected from ComboBox1 and CommandButton1 is pressed to export just the selected sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If (ComboBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox ("Select a sheet to Export to PDF.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rngRange = Worksheets("DM").Range("D10")
    If ComboBox1.Value = "TR" Then
        setname = "Treatment Report"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "DM" Then
        setname = "Data Master Cover"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "JHA" Then
        setname = "JHA"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "SIGN" Then
        setname = "Safety Meeting Sign In Sheet"
    Else
        setname = Worksheets("DM").Range("B41")
    End If
    bolSelected = True
    strDirname = Worksheets("DM").Range("B41") & " " & Worksheets("DM").Range("D9") & " " & rngRange.Value
    strFileName = Worksheets("DM").Range("B41") & " " & Worksheets("DM").Range("D9") & " " & rngRange.Value & " " & setname
    strDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\" & strDirname
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strDir
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=strDir & "\" & strFileName, openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
    MsgBox "File exported to My Documents.", , "EXPORT COMPLETE"
    Worksheets("DM").Select
End Sub
```

When all the sheets that the user requires is exported (it could be one or two or three or all of them), the user presses CommandButton2, which asks to email the sheets they exported, if yes it will run through this email form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If bolSelected = True Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to email exported files now?", vbYesNo, "EMAIL ITEMS") = vbYes Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If Err.Number = 429 Then
                Shell "outlook.exe", vbNormalFocus
            Else
                AppActivate objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Caption
            End If
            Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            With OutApp
                .Session.Logon
                Set OutMail = .CreateItem(olMailItem) '0
            End With
            strDirname = strDirname & "\"
            strDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\" & strDirname
            strFileName = Dir(strDir)
            strbody = "This file was sent by " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            Application.UserName & vbNewLine & _
            "on " & Format(Date, "MMMM/dd/yyyy")
            With OutMail
                While Len(strFileName) > 0
                      .Attachments.Add (strDir & strFileName)
                      strFileName = Dir
                Wend
                .Subject = (MySub)
                .Body = strbody
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain '1
                .Display True
            End With
            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing
            Unload Me
        Else
            Unload Me
        End If
    Else
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

I created a new Module called "Post_Office" that all email code uses, "SendEmail", this workbook has 6 of the above code scattered about. SendEmail works on 5 out of the 6 as if there are attachments, they will always exist.

This is the only Userform where the files attached to an email may or may not exist.

Is there a way to get the files created from this Userform to attach to the email like the While Wend statement from above?

Comment: How exactly are you reading the filenames?

Comment: From the Userform, user selects loaded worksheet from ComboBox. `If ComboBox1.Value = "X" Then setname = "X"` `strDirname` is created from Sheet.Range values. `strFileName` is also created from Sheet.Range values including the `setname` from the ComboBox. `strDir` is the MyDocs folder and it's all exported to PDF as `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=strDir & "\" & strFileName, openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False` 

This is all done from CommandButton1 and the email code is done from ComandButton2, when the Userform is closed.

Comment: You should give the command buttons more descriptive names. Use the properties window to edit attributes such as this.

Comment: To answer your actual question if you are exporting each item as a PDF then you can construct the filename string outside of the export method (ie before `FileName:=`), add that value to a collection, and pass that collection to the `SendEmail` method.

Comment: I would but since I inherited this and this Userform has two buttons, "CommandButton1" and "CommandButton2", I understand what both buttons do. I don't think it's necessary to be descriptive when I can look at the code and know what it does. 

Thank you for the suggestion though. The issue I am having is adding files from a folder to the attachment argument from the SendEmail function as the legacy code uses a While Wend statement and I can't figure out how to add that loop to the argument.

Comment: I was trying to construct a collection but to no avail, it still doesn't display the Outlook Send Email window when the macro runs. I assume it is still trying to use empty values and I assume I am passing that data incorrectly.

Comment: It is just good principle to name things descriptively. If you inherited it someone might inherit from you and so on. Also if anyone else ends up looking at the code. I know not directly to your question but something I saw and thought to note.

Comment: If you are assuming that use step through debugging with the watch window to see if the variable values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: strDirname must be defined as global in the UserForm VBA module like this Public strDirname, you have .Attachment.Add() non existent file in CommandButton2_Click(). And please try to use well debugged SendMail() in your click event.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by ParamArray VBA, `ParamArray attachments()`, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal recipient As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal bodyText As String, SendDisplay As Boolean, ByVal carboncopy As String, _
  ParamArray attachments())

    Dim x
    Dim OutMail As Object, objOutlook As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Shell "outlook.exe", vbNormalFocus
        Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Else
        AppActivate objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Caption
    End If
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    With objOutlook
        .Session.Logon
        Set OutMail = .CreateItem(olMailItem)
    End With
    With OutMail
        .To = recipient
        If carboncopy <> "" Then
            .CC = carboncopy
        End If
        .subject = subject
        .Body = bodyText
        
        For Each x In attachments
          If x <> "" Then
            .attachments.Add x
          End If
        Next
        
        If SendDisplay Then
            .Display True
        Else
            .Send
        End If
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

'
' SendEmail "", (MySub), strbody, True, , ???
'
Sub doSendmail()
  SendEmail "johndoe@example.com", "Test", "Hello body", True, "", "filename", "filename2", "filename3", "filename4"
End Sub
```

We replace with this loop to add attachments():

```
        For Each x In attachments
          If x <> "" Then
            .attachments.Add x
          End If
        Next
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it. The issue I am having now is that I added a construct to assemble the file location based on the `setname` variable. This will create a new variable based on the ComboBox1 selection and Export button press. I added all these variables into the `sendemail` argument as `SendEmail "", "Export Single sheet PDF", strbody, True, "", TICattach, TRattach, TR2attach, DMattach, JHAattach, SIGNattach` The Outlook window doesn't display as I assume that blank values is causing an error. I should have been more clear as 1 up to all items can be emailed.

Comment: Have you test with an email address as a the first argument ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested with and without (""). I also stepped through the code and I does add the variable to x with the file location for the attachment. It seems like everything is fine but it doesn't display the Outlook Send Email window.

Comment: You should check existence of files, .attachment.Add require existent files, any nonexistent file will cause no window of outlook mail. I've captured an image for you.

Comment: I believe that is what is happening. With the legacy code it uses the While Wend to add the attachments that exist in this folder created by this  macro. `While Len(strFileName) > 0 .Attachments.Add (strDir & strFileName) strFileName = Dir Wend` (As in OP) Either 1 or all exported PDFs can be attached to the email. I think because some of the values are nothing, it is causing the Outlook Send Email not to display. Is there a way to get the existing files from the folder to attach to the argument? Or if the variable is not blank, add it to the attachment argument.

Comment: I edited the Original Post to reflect the legacy code for this issue and how the original email code attached the files to the email.

Comment: I've finally found the solution. I used a `Do While` loop to loop through the folder for exported PDFs from the CommandButton1 macro then add the files to an array, `SEattachArray(Counter) = (strDir & MyFile)`. Since your Paramarry looks for "", all existing files are populated first and non-existing files are left as "". So when I use `SendEmail "", "", strbody, True, "", SEattachArray(0), SEattachArray(1), SEattachArray(2), SEattachArray(3), SEattachArray(4), SEattachArray(5)` all existing items are first with will allow the `For Each X In attachments` to populate first, preventing the error

Comment: Great, OK all your attached path are now existent files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an array to get the data I needed in to the `paramarray` argument.

```
strbody = "This file was sent by " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
Application.UserName & vbNewLine & _
"on " & Format(Date, "MMMM/dd/yyyy")
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Counter As Long
Dim SEattachArray() As String
ReDim SEattachArray(6)
MyFile = Dir$(strDir)
Do While MyFile <> ""
    SEattachArray(Counter) = (strDir & MyFile)
    MyFile = Dir$
    Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
SendEmail "", "", strbody, True, "", SEattachArray(0), SEattachArray(1), SEattachArray(2), SEattachArray(3), SEattachArray(4), SEattachArray(5)
```

`SendEmail` will populate existing files first followed by non-existing files, allowing `X` to ignore null values from the `paramarray` argument allowing the argument to pass and open the Outlook Send Email window and attach the files.

```
For Each X In attachments
  If X <> "" Then
    .attachments.Add X
  End If
Next
```